# Какой код ответа необходимо вернуть при уже существующей записи?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Допустим что пользователь хочет добавить страну в базу данных, но не знает существует ли она.

Отправляет пост запрос с названием страны, при принятии запроса я проверяю существует ли такая страна:

```
// POST: api/countries
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Country>> PostCountry(Country country)
{
    bool isExist = Enumerable.Any(_context.Countries, contextCountry => contextCountry.Name == country.Name);

    if (isExist)
    {
        return Conflict(country); // or return 406 Not Acceptable or 208 Already Reported
    }

    _context.Countries.Add(country);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCountry", new { id = country.Id }, country);
}
```

Какой из следующих кодов ответа лучше возвращать при уже существующей записи?

1. 208 Already Reported
2. 406 Not Acceptable
3. 409 Conflict

Или может есть код который сообщает о том что ресурс существует?

Comment: Напишите в поисковике `restapi status codes` и увидите много сайтов, которые описывают все коды. Например [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/messaging-cloud/csmes/rest-api-http-status-codes-and-error-messages-reference.html#GUID-AAB1EE32-BE4A-4ACC-BEAC-ABA85EB41919) - `409 Conflict - An attempt was made to create an object that already exists.`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, т.е. если так подумать, то это зависит от разработчика какой код будет возвращен?

Comment: Ну у всех свои стандарты. +- везде они одинаковы, но расхождения есть, да. Да и как по мне, отсылать просто код, не очень хорошо, стоит еще выслать сообщение, которое будет описывать подробно проблему, ибо тот же 409 может подразумевать многое и тому, кто будет использовать это API придется гадать. Взять того же Oracle, то у них выдается еще и код ошибки, например `consumerAlreadyExists` и вы можете посмотреть на той странице, что я дал, 409 код у них относится как минимум к 8 ошибкам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Понял, но если о стандартах, дуамаю в моем случае можно просто вернуть сам найденный объект :) Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Двухсотые коды - это успех. Считать ли наличие записи успехом?